# R: Merging two date columns into one in order by id

Tags: r, data.table

I am currently working in R in data table and have two date columns (first_day and last_day) that I need to merge together into one date column (date). This needs to be done so that the column has the dates in order from smallest to largest by group (id).

Here is the data I'm working with:

```
ID    first_day    last_day
1     1/12/2005    1/15/2005
2     2/15/2006    2/19/2006
2     3/8/2006     3/12/2006
3     1/9/2008     1/13/2008
```

Here is what I'm trying to get the result to look like:

```
ID    first_day    last_day    Date
1     1/12/2005    1/15/2005   1/12/2005 
1     1/12/2005    1/15/2005   1/15/2005
2     2/15/2006    2/19/2006   2/15/2006
2     2/15/2006    2/19/2006   2/19/2006
2     3/8/2006     3/12/2006   3/8/2006
2     3/8/2006     3/12/2006   3/12/2006
3     1/9/2008     1/13/2008   1/9/2008
3     1/9/2008     1/13/2008   1/13/2008
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
out <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), each = 2),] # repeat each row
out$Date <- with(df, c(rbind(first_day, last_day))) # interlace two columns
# or out$Date <- with(out, ifelse(seq_along(first_day) %% 2, first_day, last_day))    

out
#     ID first_day  last_day      Date
# 1    1 1/12/2005 1/15/2005 1/12/2005
# 1.1  1 1/12/2005 1/15/2005 1/15/2005
# 2    2 2/15/2006 2/19/2006 2/15/2006
# 2.1  2 2/15/2006 2/19/2006 2/19/2006
# 3    2  3/8/2006 3/12/2006  3/8/2006
# 3.1  2  3/8/2006 3/12/2006 3/12/2006
# 4    3  1/9/2008 1/13/2008  1/9/2008
# 4.1  3  1/9/2008 1/13/2008 1/13/2008
```

or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, .(Date = c(first_day, last_day)), by = .(ID, first_day, last_day)]
#    ID first_day  last_day      Date
# 1:  1 1/12/2005 1/15/2005 1/12/2005
# 2:  1 1/12/2005 1/15/2005 1/15/2005
# 3:  2 2/15/2006 2/19/2006 2/15/2006
# 4:  2 2/15/2006 2/19/2006 2/19/2006
# 5:  2  3/8/2006 3/12/2006  3/8/2006
# 6:  2  3/8/2006 3/12/2006 3/12/2006
# 7:  3  1/9/2008 1/13/2008  1/9/2008
# 8:  3  1/9/2008 1/13/2008 1/13/2008
```

Answer (score 3):

We can group by row, concatenate the 'first_day', 'last_day' into a `list` column and do `unnest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   rowwise() %>%       
    mutate(Date = list(c(first_day, last_day))) %>%
    unnest(Date)
```

Or with `map2`, create the `list` column and then do the `unnest`

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(Date = map2(first_day, last_day, c)) %>%
  unnest(Date)
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#     ID first_day last_day  Date     
#  <int> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
#1     1 1/12/2005 1/15/2005 1/12/2005
#2     1 1/12/2005 1/15/2005 1/15/2005
#3     2 2/15/2006 2/19/2006 2/15/2006
#4     2 2/15/2006 2/19/2006 2/19/2006
#5     2 3/8/2006  3/12/2006 3/8/2006 
#6     2 3/8/2006  3/12/2006 3/12/2006
#7     3 1/9/2008  1/13/2008 1/9/2008 
#8     3 1/9/2008  1/13/2008 1/13/2008
```

---

Or using `uncount`

```
uncount(df1, 2) %>%
        mutate(Date = c(t(df1[-1])))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), first_day = c("1/12/2005", 
"2/15/2006", "3/8/2006", "1/9/2008"), last_day = c("1/15/2005", 
"2/19/2006", "3/12/2006", "1/13/2008")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R solution:

```
dfout <- Reduce(rbind,
                lapply(split(df,seq(nrow(df))), 
                       function(x) cbind(x,Date = unlist(x[-1]),row.names = NULL)))
```

or a faster way using `do.call()`

```
dfout <- do.call(rbind, 
                 c(make.row.names = FALSE, 
                   lapply(split(df,seq(nrow(df))), 
                          function(x) cbind(x,Date = unlist(x[-1]),row.names = NULL))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  ID first_day  last_day      Date
1  1 1/12/2005 1/15/2005 1/12/2005
2  1 1/12/2005 1/15/2005 1/15/2005
3  2 2/15/2006 2/19/2006 2/15/2006
4  2 2/15/2006 2/19/2006 2/19/2006
5  2  3/8/2006 3/12/2006  3/8/2006
6  2  3/8/2006 3/12/2006 3/12/2006
7  3  1/9/2008 1/13/2008  1/9/2008
8  3  1/9/2008 1/13/2008 1/13/2008
```

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Thanks again, now it is updated! What do you mean by "risk of appreaing critical"? I am curious about it